# Shopify: How do I create a new button that will redirect to the Product page?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm new here and also fairly new to coding in Liquid/JSON. I'm working on a Shopify project where I need to create a new button placed right below the product price. The button will read "Learn More" and once clicked it will direct the user to the product page. I believe I located the right liquid file and the code needs to be added here so it will appear in the Featured Collection section of the theme.

I'm not creating a new Featured Collection section from scratch, but altering the theme's existing code.

```
{% render 'section--featured-collection' with
 heading: section.settings.title,
 collection: collections[section.settings.collection],
 per_row: section.settings.per_row,
 rows: section.settings.rows,
 aspect_ratio: section.settings.aspect_ratio
%}

{% schema %}
 {
  "name": "t:sections.featured_collection.name",
  "class": "inline-section",
  "templates": ["404", "article", "blog", "cart", "collection", "list-collections", 
  "customers/account", "customers/activate_account", "customers/addresses", 
  "customers/login", "customers/order", "customers/register", 
  "customers/reset_password", "gift_card", "index", "page", "product", "search"],

   "settings": [
    {
     "id": "collection",
     "type": "collection",
     "label": "t:sections.featured_collection.settings.collection.label"
    },
    {
     "id": "title",
     "type": "text",
     "label": "t:sections.featured_collection.settings.title.label",
     "default": "Featured collection"
    },
    {
     "type": "range",
     "id": "per_row",
     "label": "t:sections.featured_collection.settings.per_row.label",
     "min": 2,
     "max": 4,
     "step": 1,
     "default": 3
    },
    {
     "type": "range",
     "id": "rows",
     "label": "t:sections.featured_collection.settings.rows.label",
     "min": 1,
     "max": 3,
     "step": 1,
     "default": 1
    },
    {
     "id": "aspect_ratio",
     "type": "select",
     "label": "t:shared.aspect_ratio.label",
     "options": [
      { "label": "t:shared.aspect_ratio.options.natural", "value": "natural" },
      { "label": "t:shared.aspect_ratio.options.square", "value": "square" },
      { "label": "t:shared.aspect_ratio.options.landscape", "value": "landscape" },
      { "label": "t:shared.aspect_ratio.options.portrait", "value": "portrait" }
     ],
     "default": "natural"
    }    
   ],
  "presets": [
  {
    "name": "Featured collection",
    "category": "Collection",
    "settings": {}
  }
  ]
  }
 {% endschema %}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated and a HUGE help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `section--featured-collection` snippet, when looping over products of the featured collection, it's pretty standard to refer to each product's url using the `product.url` property.

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
  <!-- Typically more information, like product image, title and price -->
  <a href="{{ product.url }}">Learn More</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You can find more information on the product properties in the [Shopify doc](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product).